# Обход дерева dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, dom, foreach, dropdown

Есть стандартное генерируемое меню типа dropdown, допустим на 3 уровня.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>Ссылка 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>Ссылка 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                    <a>Ссылка 3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Кажется так написал. В каждой ul>li содержится ссылка и следующая ul>li, если это не последний уровень. Например мне нужно поставить маркеры на все , которые не являются последним уровнем, то есть по соседству с которой есть еще ul>li. Как это реализовать? Рекурсией?

Comment: Что за маркеры?

Comment: Например треугольнички, говорящие что есть еще подпункты в этом пункте, и что его можно развернуть, неважно, главное выбрать эту <a>

Comment: Ну вы бы добавили JavaScript код хоть какой-нить по теме, что вы там с ними делаете. А то окажется потом, что еще `onclick` надо вешать на них.

Answer (score 1):

Мб оффтоп, но если вам только стрелки расставить надо, то поищите решения основанные на CSS. Я в нем, правда, не специалист, но возможно, нечто подобное, или прочие варианты.

```css
li > a::after {
   content: '\2bc6';
   color: red;
}

li > a:only-child::after {
 content: '';
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>Ссылка 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>Ссылка 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                    <a>Ссылка 3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Либо с помошью jquery (можете портировать в js), фактически рекурсия то тут не требуется.

```js
$("li > a").each(function(){
   if($(this).next("ul").length){
      $(this).addClass("dropdown");
   }
});
```

```css
a.dropdown::after {
  content: '\2bc6';
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>Ссылка 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>Ссылка 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                    <a>Ссылка 3</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```